# How date function retrieve information in php?

Tags: php

i am trying using date() function in php on localhost.But the date is changed whenever i am changing my computer's date and time. If i upload the php file on a live server then what will happen? will **Changing** clients computer date work like that????please its important....

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 
$today = date("m.d.y");                         
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       
$today = date("Ymd");                           
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     
$today = date("H:i:s");                         
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

i am using those function.....

Comment: Your local computer acts like a server, so analogously the date would change if the online _server_ would change its clock (which won't)

Answer (score 1):

On your localhost, your computer is the server.  So, changing the your computer's (server's) time changes the displayed time.  On a host environment, the hosting server dictates the displayed time.

Answer (score 0):

The date function shows you the date on the computer ("server") where PHP is running.

So when you run the PHP locally on your machine, PHP reports the time on your machine through the date() function.

When you run it on another machine, it is that machine's time that is reported.

To test it for yourself, without a "live server" as such, run the web server on your machine, and use another different machine on your local area network to access the site, using your computer's IP address.  You will see it is your computer's time - not the time of the computer you are running the web browser on - that is reported.